# NumericUpDown custom increment using default Buttons

Tags: c#, winforms, button, numeric, numericupdown

I have a NumericUpDown control with increment of `5`. Entering `1` using the keyboard is possible and shall always be possible.
But when I click the Up-button I want not to have a `6` but a `5`, always `5`, `10`, `15`...

How is this possible? In `ValueChange` this is not possible, because I want the possibility to enter every single number by keyboard.

Comment: This may help: https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.numericupdown.increment?view=netcore-3.1

Comment: When you define the increment of 5 it's considered as a role to your NumericUpDown control. You shouldn't allow to input any value because it breaks your previous restriction of increment 5.

Comment: But how to detect if it came from the buttons and not from the textfield?

Comment: You can create custom user control with textbox and two buttons and handle it as you like. As a bonus you can add more buttons (+5, +10, -5, -10, etc.) to enrich user experience.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can derive a Custom Control from NumericUpDown, override both [UpButton()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.updownbase.upbutton) and [DownButton()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.updownbase.downbutton) to provide a custom logic to apply to the **`Increment`** value.

Here, setting the Increment to `5`, the NumericUpDown Buttons (and the <kbd>UP</kbd> and <kbd>DOWN</kbd> keys, if [InterceptArrowKeys](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.updownbase.interceptarrowkeys) is set to `true`), will increment or decrement the Value by `5`.
If the User enters a different value with the keyboard, the value is accepted, unless it exceeds the `Maximum` and `Minimum` pre-sets. In this case, the Control is reset to the `Maximum` or `Minimum` value.

E.g., a User enters `16`: if the `UpButton` is pressed, the value will be set to `20`, to `15` if the `DownButton` is pressed instead.
In either case, the Value entered cannot exceed the upper and lower bounds.

Note that neither `base.UpButton()` or `base.DownButton()` are called, since these would adjust the Value to the Increment set using the standard method.

```
class NumericUpDpwnCustomIncrement : NumericUpDown
{
    public NumericUpDpwnCustomIncrement() { }

    public override void UpButton() => 
        Value = Math.Min(Value + (Increment - (Value % Increment)), Maximum);

    public override void DownButton() => 
        Value = Math.Max(Value - (Value % Increment == 0 ? Increment : Value % Increment), Minimum);

    protected override void OnValueChanged(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnValueChanged(e);
        Value = Math.Max(Math.Min(Value, Maximum), Minimum);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use NumbericUpDown [Click](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.click?view=netcore-3.1) event. It is called when up/down buttons are clicked.

```
private void OnClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    numericUpDown.Value -= numericUpDown.Value % 5;
}
```

**Edit**: since the event also gets called when the Textfield is clicked, I propose another solution.

You can override NumericUpDown methods [UpButton](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.numericupdown.upbutton?view=netcore-3.1) and [DownButton](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.numericupdown.downbutton?view=netcore-3.1) to trigger an event.

```
public class MyNumericUpDown : System.Windows.Forms.NumericUpDown
{
    public event Action OnButtonPressed;
    
    public override void UpButton()
    {
        base.UpButton();
        OnButtonPressed?.Invoke();
    }

    public override void DownButton()
    {
        base.DownButton();
        OnButtonPressed?.Invoke();
    }
}
```

And inside YourForm.Designer.cs rewrite `this.numericUpDown = new System.Windows.Forms.NumericUpDown();` to `this.numericUpDown = new YourNamespace.MyNumericUpDown();`.

Then in your Form construcor add:

```
numericUpDown.OnButtonPressed += () => numericUpDown.Value -= numericUpDown.Value % 5;
```

Comment: This also is called when I click into the Textfield to enter a number